# How would I add a percentage to a width that is a percentage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to increase the filled amount of a progress bar. I am using the following code to say that whenever the function `nxt()` is called it increases the percentage that the div takes by 3.3% (example: width is 2.0% add 3.3% and get 5.3%). I am using the following code at the moment to try to do this:

```
document.getElementById("pb").style.width = 
`${document.getElementById("pb").style.width + 3.3}` ;
```

(the width of the div w/ the id pb is 0%)

This isn't working however. `document.getElementById("pb").style.width + 3.3` outputs 0%3.3 and when i try `document.getElementById("pb").style.width + 3.3%` it  doesn't work either with no output. Could someone help me figure out how I can get the percentage I want? Thanks!

Comment: can you please specify what does this 'document.getElementById("pb").style.width' returns? as answers seem a little ambiguous cause some of them are adding direct 3.3 to the returned value which in my opinion is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're assigning `%`s, `style.width` returns a *string* which includes `%` at the end. You need to strip off the `%` so you can get the numeric percentage, add a number to it, and assign it to the `width` property again:

```js
const pbStyle = document.getElementById("pb").style;
function increment() {
  const percentage = Number(pbStyle.width.slice(0, -1));
  const newPercentage = Math.min(percentage + 3.3, 100);
  pbStyle.width = `${newPercentage}%`;
  console.log(pbStyle.width);
  if (newPercentage < 100) setTimeout(increment, 100);
}
increment();
```

```css
#pb {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="pb">progress</div>
```

Or, you might keep the current percentage in a variable instead:

```js
const pbStyle = document.getElementById("pb").style;
let percentage = 0;
function increment() {
  percentage = Math.min(percentage + 3.3, 100);
  pbStyle.width = `${percentage}%`;
  console.log(pbStyle.width);
  if (percentage < 100) setTimeout(increment, 100);
}
increment();
```

```css
#pb {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="pb">progress</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is working well for me however it is acting a bit strange. after adding the initial 3.3% to the 0% it works correctly summing up to 3.3%, but afterward it just adds 3 (so 3.3 + 3.3 =  6.3 is what is gives). How would I fix this?

Comment: Ops, use `slice(0, -1)` instead of `slice(0, -2)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance your second piece of code is bugging me a little. you set percentage value to 0 by default and add 3.3 to it, so if a progress bar has some default value it won't matter and it will be updating the progress bar using the hard-coded values?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil I suppose you *could* if something *else* initially set the width of the progress bar, but for a progress bar that's being updated and modified with Javascript, that sounds pretty unlikely (as well as introducing unnecessary complications) - if the Javascript initializes it, which it should, there's no need to check the existing style.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perfect! that addresses my complications. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you say increase the width by 3.3%, you mean increase the width of the 'pb' element by 3.3% of the parent element.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("pb").style.width = 
    document.getElementById("pb").clientWidth + 
    0.033*document.getElementById('parent-div').clientWidth;
```

Comment: 'clientWidth'  will round the value to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the width of the progress bar and multiply it with `0.033` which will give you the 3.3% width of your progress bar.

do this instead:

```
document.getElementById("pb").style.width =  (parseFloat(document.getElementById("pb").style.width) * 0.33 ) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("pb").style.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly concatenating your values, not adding. As you can check in your developers tool the statement `document.getElementById("pb").style.width` returns a string. So what you can do is:

```
var newWidth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pb").style.width) + 3.3;
document.getElementById("pb").style.width = newWidth + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the width as a float and then add the amount you want:

```
document.getElementById("pb").style.width = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("pb").style.width) + 3.3) + '%';
```